# global array filled with method result

Tags: java, arrays, global

I have a global array, not initialized, a method with a loop that returns a tmpArray and should fill myArray, but I'm getting an empty myArray. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or where is the problem.

Post edited with myMethod code:

global:

```
int myArray[] =null;


code sample:

myArray [] = myMethod();

   private int [] myMethid (int option){
    int [] tmpArray = new int[99];
    int a=0,b=0;

    System.out.println( "bla bla bla bla "+option+": \n" +
            "------------------------------------------------------------------");
       for(int i=0;i<99;i++){
        System.out.println("bla bla bla bla bla bla ");
         a = Integer.parseInt(lector.nextLine());



        if (a==-1){
            menu();
        }else{
            if (a > 9){
                System.out.println("bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ");
                i--;                
            }else{
               i++;
                tmpArray[i]=a;

            }
             System.out.println("bla bla bla bla bla bla  "+ a);
            b = Integer.parseInt(lector.nextLine());

            tmpArray[i+1]=b;

            System.out.println(tmpArray[i] +"x" + otherArray[tmpArray[i+1]]+"\n");

        }



    } 
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmpArray));
     return tmpArray; 
}
```

Comment: post `myMethod();` code.

Comment: `otherMethod` is a method or an array?

Comment: sorry, other array, edited

Comment: Is possible you have two similar methods myMethid and myMethod and you are called the wrong one?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `tmpArray[i+1]=b;` to be `tmpArray[++i]=b;`? and then `otherArray[tmpArray[i+1]]` will be `otherArray[tmpArray[i]]` Because maybe indexs are going just wrong (but it don't justice the empty array...)

Comment: here I'm seeing it good: System.out.println(tmpArray[i] +"x" + otherArray[tmpArray[i+1]]+"\n");

Comment: but here shows nothing  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmpArray));

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return an array you should say to the method to return an array, then create it in the method and return the reference.

Something like:

```
private int[] myMethod()
{
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: yup, sorry, I'm doing it like this, the difference is I'm filling that array with a loop, and when it ends i'm returning the result

Comment: I've added a little sample code, I'm sure the array inside is filling correctly, don't know if I must initializate first the globar array to fill it with tmpArray?

Comment: Are you sure? No, you will just lose the memory allocated first when you change the reference. Make sure tmpArray contains values before return!

Comment: well, I'm doing prints on each loop and I'm seeing data :/ where can b this data lost?

Comment: Add `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmpArray));` before return line and see what contains

Comment: its empty :/ but don't know why

Comment: i posted a comment in the main answer